# Unable to change MySQL column type with PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to change Mysql column type from phpmyadmin . The type
which was already assigned was `SMALLINT`. This column contain data in
it and I want to change it to `VARCHAR`.

I am Getting an error:

```
 Query error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED NOT NULL' at line 1
```

Comment: Show your sql statement please.

Comment: Since you haven't shown us the actual query we have no idea what is going wrong. This is similar to taking a picture of the closeup of one of your headlamps of your car, sending it to a mechanic and asking him to diagnose the engine.

Comment: @h2ooooooo that is the greatest, but strangest analogy I've ever read.

Comment: i am not using any statement .I am using Chang option from Action of phpmyadmin

Comment: My reputation is 3 so sending pic facilities  is not available for me

Comment: Even if you don't write a query, phpmyadmin display the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is very clear: there is an error near `UNSIGNED`. You want to change the type of the column to `VARCHAR`, it probably is `UNSIGNED SMALLINT` now.

There is no thing like `UNSIGNED VARCHAR` and this is the cause of the error.

If you change the type to `VARCHAR` don't forget to enter a size and **uncheck** `UNSIGNED`, `ZEROFILL` and `AUTOINCREMENT`. These properties are available only for integer types. They don't make any sense on the string types.

Comment: I have change attribute to UNSIGNED to UNSIGNED  ZEROFILL and in my table there is already one AUTOINCREMENT ,after following your suggestion i am getting an error   Query error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL' at line 1

Comment: Read my answer again. It says **uncheck**. That means **don't use**.